# How do I Raise an Event when the Binding is completed?

Tags: silverlight, events, xaml, binding, raise

I have a TextBox in my application that i am developing and the binding is done in the xaml

I want to be able to raise an event when the binding of the TextBox Text Property is completed meaning when the text is loaded/changed through binding into the TextBox how do i achive this?

I tried TextChanged Event also Loaded Event but no luck right after the Binding is complected so how do i do it?

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxCategories" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" Padding="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=discussion_categoryDomainDataSource, Path=Data}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelCategory" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCategoryId" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryID}" />
                        <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ForumExpanderStyleRight}">
                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="4,0,4,0" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" LayoutUpdated="TextBlock_LayoutUpdated" />
                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <ListBox x:Name="listBoxBoards" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryBoards}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="GridBoard">
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </toolkit:Expander>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

at this line

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCategoryId" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryID}" />
```

I want an event where when the Binding is completed i want to give a different data source for the list box under the parent stack panel so i need the binding event so when i have the catedory id int he text block which later will be hidden in the xaml ( which now is not collapsed for testing reasons )

Comment: I have a textbox and i am binding it in a list box in a datatemplate and when the textbox text is set through binding i want to be able to raise an event or if there is a binding done event i want to do something else with other controls but first i want that when this text box Text property is populated through binding raise an event which says that yest this text property is changed ( i tried Loaded and textChanged Event but thry don't work as how i want when i do Loaded the UI freezes and when TextChanged is used it doen't raise event at binding time but later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem for me :)

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="4,0,4,0" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
```

Loaded event in the inner Text block rather than the upper textblock because by the time this is loaded the upper text block's text is already bound so i can retrive the ID :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly peculiar thing to want to do, it might help if you tell us why you are wanting to do this?

However, with no other information to hand, I will propose a solution.

If the TextBox API events do not provide the infomation you need, try handing the `LayoutUpdated` event. This event fires each time layout occurs, which is typically as elements ae added to the visual tree. WHen this event fires inspect your `TextBox.Text` property to see if it is set.

Comment: i added more clarity the LayoutUpdate mostly gives me a null sender i need it to be the TextBlock/TextBox which will be hidden later in the front end